# How can I get a list of all hexadecimal colors of a bitmap?

Tags: actionscript-3

How, through actionscript3, and not crashing (flash stucks while getting), can I get a list of all hexadecimal colors of a bitmap.

This bitmap it´s not extense (340x230)

Thanks

Comment: What type of output do you want? An array of hex numbers? Why do you need this? I'm assuming you want unique colours (no duplicates)?

Comment: I need it to make the bitmap area with this color walkable in a pathfinder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping through a vector will be faster than getPixel:

```
var lookupMap:Object = {};
var v:Vector.<uint> = bitmapData.getVector(bitmapData.rect)
var colors:Array = [];

for each (var color:uint in v) {
    if (lookupMap[color] !== true) {
        colors.push(color);
        lookupMap[color] = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its got nothing to do with Flash "sucking", its a simple problem. If your crashing, your doing something wrong.

```
var lookupMap:Object = {};
var bmd:BitmapData = somebitmapDataObject;
var colours:Array = [];

for(var i:int=0; i<bmd.height; i++) {
    for(var j:int=0; j<bmd.width; j++) {
        var colour:uint = bmd.getPixel(j,i);
        if(lookupMap[colour] !== true) {
            colours.push(colour);
            lookupMap[colour] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Code not tested for bugs.

Comment: Very nice, don't forget to discard `lookMap` at the end.

Comment: AS3 is a garbage collected language, you can't discard things. GC will do all it needs to do in time.

Comment: Hmm, true, though I feel uneasy about keeping that huge object just chillin' there until GC wakes up - maybe just at least clean it up?

Comment: You could null the object, but it won't make any difference. The reference will be lost as soon as the function call ends any ways. If the lookup object is class level for some reason, (it shouldn't be), then I'll agree :) The object will exist in memory until the GC runs no matter what you do.